# Callback was already called in async.forEach when using Redis Multi()

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a set of Sections where I need to get the records pertaining to each section.
All records are stored in Hash in Redis.

But when the below code is executed it gives Callback was already called.

```
function GetData_Redis(sectionsList)
{
    var async = require('async');
    var sectionResults = []; 
    var regex = new RegExp(' ', 'g');

    var redisMultiClient = require("redis").createClient(6379, 'XXXX', { auth_pass: 'XXXX' }).multi();

    async.forEach(sectionsList, function taskIterator(sectionItem, callback) 
    {
        var sectionName = sectionItem.name.replace(regex, "");

        sectionName = sectionName.toLowerCase() + ":";

        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
        {
            redisMultiClient.hgetall(sectionName + i);
        }

        redisMultiClient.exec(function (error, replies) 
        {
            if (error) 
            {
                callback(err);
            }
            else 
            {
                if (replies.length > 0)
                    sectionResults.push({ section_id : sectionItem.section_id, name : sectionItem.name, articles : replies });

                callback(null);
            }
        });
    },
    function () 
    {
        redisMultiClient.quit();
        console.log("came here");
    });
}
```

But when I use the below code inside the forEach and quit it after execution it works but order is not maintained.

```
var redisMultiClient = require("redis").createClient(6379, 'XXXX', { auth_pass: 'XXXX' }).multi();
```

So how do I solve it.

Comment: The simplest way would be to get rid of the multi/exec construct.  That gives you transaction guarantees which you don't need for this. Instead just do the multiple `hgetall`-calls without multi/exec

Comment: Each and every section I have to get 20 records and there around 10 sections so it will be around 200 calls for Cache server. Is it correct since this is a webservice which is called very frequently from websites.